# Symfony 2 ParamConverter with repository_method does not return correct result

Tags: symfony

i have an issue with ParamConverter option "repository_method"

Here is a "standard" request in my controller :

```
public function viewmessageAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('LAPContactBundle:Contact');
        $message = $repository->findMessage($id);

        if(null === $message) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Le message d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
        }
            die(var_dump($message));
    }
```

And the result :

```
array (size=11)
  'id' => int 1
  'dateContact' => 
    object(DateTime)[756]
      public 'date' => string '2016-12-13 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
  'choix' => string 'Problème sur le site internet' (length=30)
  'nom' => string 'Personne' (length=8)
  'prenom' => string 'Paul' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'paul.personne@gmail.com' (length=23)
  'telephone' => int 607080910
  'texte' => string 'Bonjour, c'est pour faire un message de test en fait je n'existe pas mouahahahah' (length=80)
  'traite' => int 1
  'dateTraite' => 
    object(DateTime)[760]
      public 'date' => string '2016-12-14 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
  'username' => string 'mike' (length=4)
```

Where i have the last result 'username'.

And here the controller with ParamConverter :

```
/**
* @ParamConverter("post", class="LAPContactBundle:Contact", options={"repository_method" = "findMessage"})
*/
public function viewmessageAction($id, Request $request, Contact $message)
{
        die(var_dump($message));
}
```

And the result :

```
object(LAP\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact)[243]
  private 'id' => int 1
  private 'nom' => string 'Personne' (length=8)
  private 'prenom' => string 'Paul' (length=4)
  private 'email' => string 'paul.personne@gmail.com' (length=23)
  private 'telephone' => int 607080910
  private 'texte' => string 'Bonjour, c'est pour faire un message de test en fait je n'existe pas mouahahahah' (length=80)
  private 'dateContact' => 
    object(DateTime)[212]
      public 'date' => string '2016-12-13 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
  private 'choix' => string 'Problème sur le site internet' (length=30)
  private 'traite' => int 1
  private 'dateTraite' => 
    object(DateTime)[214]
      public 'date' => string '2016-12-14 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
  private 'idTraite' => int 1
```

Here i do not have 'username', instead i have the id for the join

Could someone help me ?

> Edit

It seems that the paramconverter returns the find() method and not the custom method findMessage()

Comment: Could be a lazy loading issue.  Does dump($contact->getUsername()) produce the expected output?

Comment: It does with the first method but none with the second one. idTraite = the id of the user and it has to return the username

Comment: I am not seeing a repository_method in the documentation.  Might try an expression: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression And of course you might try the ever popular cache clearing though it should not be necessary if you are in development mode.

Comment: Thank you Cerad for your return. You can find the repository method here : [link](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter)
I use Symfony 3.1.8 in dev environment.
Still doesn't work so i will pursue with the old method, more efficient but less elegant ^^

Comment: Should "post" actually be "message"?

Comment: I have this error with "message" instead of "post" :
Type error: Argument 3 passed to LAP\AdminBundle\Controller\DefaultController::viewmessageAction() must be an instance of LAP\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact, array given

Comment: Of course.  For some reason your wrote findMessage to return an array instead of an object.  Your var_dump shows that clearly.  Just replace the Message typehint with array or else have findMessage return an object.  So post instead of message was the problem.

Comment: It's surprising because the query is "getOneOrNullresult" and it returns an array but it might be an instance of the entity